# Get the Column Index of a Cell in Excel using OpenXML C#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I've been looking around for a while now and cannot seem to find out how to do this. 
I've got an excel sheet, which I'm reading using OpenXML. Now the normal thing would be to loop through the rows and then loop through the cells to get the values, which is fine. But along with the values I need the location of the cell, which would be in the format (rowindex, ColumnIndex). I've managed to get the rowIndex, but cant seem to figure out getting the column Index.

I actually thought this was going to be easy but apparently it isnt.

Comment: For future readers, I recommend [seeing this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/667902/906773).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oi29500/044c2ba4-098b-4b15-b960-3f7f972665df

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is slightly trickier than you might imagine because the schema allows for empty cells to be omitted.

To get the index you can use the [`Cell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cell(v=office.14).aspx) object wihch has a [`CellReference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.celltype.cellreference(v=office.14).aspx) property that gives the reference in the format `A1`, `B1` etc. You can use that reference to extract the column number.

As you probably know, in Excel `A = 1`, `B = 2` etc up to `Z = 26` at which point the cells are prefixed with `A` to give `AA = 27`, `AB = 28` etc. Note that in the case of `AA` the first `A` has a value of 26 times the second; i.e. it is "worth" 26 whilst the second `A` is "worth" 1 giving a total of 27.

To work out the column index you can reverse the letters then take the value of the first letter and add it to a running total. Then take the value of the second letter and multiply it by 26, adding the total to the first number. For the third you multiply it by 26 twice and add it, for the fourth multiply it by 26 3 times and so on.

So for column `ABC` you would do:

```
C = 3
B = 2 * 26 = 52
A = 1 * 26 *26 = 676
3 + 52 + 676 = 731
```

In C# the following will work:

```
private static int? GetColumnIndex(string cellReference)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellReference))
    {
        return null;
    }

    //remove digits
    string columnReference = Regex.Replace(cellReference.ToUpper(), @"[\d]", string.Empty);

    int columnNumber = -1;
    int mulitplier = 1;

    //working from the end of the letters take the ASCII code less 64 (so A = 1, B =2...etc)
    //then multiply that number by our multiplier (which starts at 1)
    //multiply our multiplier by 26 as there are 26 letters
    foreach (char c in columnReference.ToCharArray().Reverse())
    {
        columnNumber += mulitplier * ((int)c - 64);

        mulitplier = mulitplier * 26;
    }

    //the result is zero based so return columnnumber + 1 for a 1 based answer
    //this will match Excel's COLUMN function
    return columnNumber + 1;
}
```

Note that the `CellReference` is *not* guaranteed to be in the XML either (although I've never seen it not there). In the case where the `CellReference` is null the cell is placed in the leftmost available cell. The `RowIndex` is also not mandatory in the spec so it too can be omitted in which case the cell is placed in the highest row available. More information can be seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186329/why-is-cell-cellreference-optional-how-do-i-get-cell-location-otherwise). The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28876001/3791802) from @BCdotWEB is correct approach in cases where the `CellReference` is `null`.

Comment: You could start with columnNumber = 0 and do not add one when returning.

Comment: What would happen with a Z in the second letter? Wouldn't it be the same as A on the third? So `Z = 26*26` and `A = 1*26*26`. I'm asking since I'm trying to do the reverse that is going from cell index to cell name.

Comment: A `Z` in the second letter is "worth" 26. That would be added to 26 times the value of the first letter. E.g. `ZZ` would be `(26 * 26) + 26 = 702`. An `A` in the 3rd column is "worth" `1`. That would be added to 26 times the value of the second letter and 26 * 26 times the value of the first. E.g `AAA` would be `(26 * 26 * 1) + (26 * 1) + 1 = 703`.

Comment: @bostero2 BTW, if that's still not clear, create a new question and ping me on here and I'll write you up an answer on how to do the reverse.

Comment: @petelids Yeah, figured it out after posting the comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Small is beautiful

```
int ColumnIndex(string reference)
{
  int ci=0;
  reference=reference.ToUpper();
  for (int ix = 0; ix < reference.Length && reference[ix] >= 'A';ix++ ) 
       ci += (ix * 26) + ((int)reference[ix] - 64);
  return ci;
}
```

Comment: Care to explain the 64?

Comment: @Yaron: 64 is ('A' - 1)

Answer (score 7):

```
    public static void CellReferenceToIndex(string reference, out int row_index, out int col_index)
    {
        row_index = 0;
        col_index = 0;

        foreach(char c in reference)
        {
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            {
                row_index = row_index * 10 + (c - '0');
            }
            if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            {
                col_index = col_index * ('Z' - 'A' + 1) + (c - 'A' + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Providing an answer to a 5 year old question that has a handful of other answers (with many upvotes) does not seem particularly useful.

Comment: Maybe not but I do like this answer better. Easier to read and way more compact.

Answer (score 5):

```
    [TestCase( 1, 0, "A1" )]
    [TestCase( 2, 25, "Z2" )]
    [TestCase( 2, 38, "AM2" )]
    [TestCase( 2, (26 * 4) + 1, "DB2" )]
    [TestCase( 2, (26 * 26 * 26 * 18) + (26 * 26 * 1) + (26 * 26 * 1) + ( 26 * 1 ) + 2, "RBAC2" )]
    public void CanGetCorrectCellReference( int row, int column, string expected )
        => GetCellReference( (uint)row, (uint)column ).Value.ShouldEqual( expected );

    public static StringValue GetCellReference( uint row, uint column ) =>
        new StringValue($"{GetColumnName("",column)}{row}");

    static string GetColumnName( string prefix, uint column ) => 
        column < 26 ? $"{prefix}{(char)( 65 + column)}" : 
        GetColumnName( GetColumnName( prefix, ( column - column % 26 ) / 26 - 1 ), column % 26 );
```

Answer (score 3):

To start answer , I invite you to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869497/openxml-how-to-get-cell-in-range/28870024?noredirect=1#comment46006747_28870024) first.

As I have explained there is **NO** easy way to extract Row and Column. The closest you get is the extraction of `CellReference` of a cell which would have the form of `A1` , `B2` which is actualy `COLUMN_ROW` format.

What you can do is extract Row and Column from the `CellReference`. Yes this would need you to implement a method where you need to check `char` by `char`to verify for numbers and strings.

Lets say you have `A11` , then when you need to index column you need to extract `A` which would give as `column 1`. Yes it's not that easy, but it's the only way unless you simply chose to count the columns when you scan/iterate through cells.

Again look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869497/openxml-how-to-get-cell-in-range/28870024?noredirect=1#comment46006747_28870024) questions answer which does the same thing.

Comment: Hmm.. OK, But I do need that column Index.So what I'm thinking now, is to find a way to replace the letter from the cell reference to get the column Index.

Comment: As explained in the answer, no EASY way :) simply count as I have pointed in the linked question :)

Comment: @QV1 Did you get the answer for the question ? Or you need more explanation :)

Comment: I got it, Thanks, Actually, since I need just the index, creating a counter for the cell loop works fine. I'll be posting my code soon, once I'm done testing. Thanks for helping out !

Comment: @QV1 Fine ,, don't forget to upvote or mark the question as correct if you think the answer helps/solves the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    Row row = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Elements<Row>().FirstOrDefault();
   var totalnumberOfColumns = 0;
    if (row != null)
        {
            var spans = row.Spans != null ? row.Spans.InnerText : "";
                if (spans != String.Empty)
                        {
                            //spans.Split(':')[1];
                            string[] columns = spans.Split(':');
                            startcolumnInuse = int.Parse(columns[0]);
                            endColumnInUse = int.Parse(columns[1]);
                            totalnumberOfColumns = int.Parse(columns[1]);
                        }
        }
```

**this is to find the total number of columns present/used** 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario I only needed to deal with column names (no cell numbers), and used LINQ, thought it's worth putting here for the reference.

```
const int AsciiTrim = 'A' - 1; //64
const int LastChar = 'Z' - AsciiTrim; //26

var colIndex = columnName
    .Reverse()
    .Select(ch => ch - AsciiTrim)
    .Select((ch, i) => ch * Math.Pow(LastChar, i))
    .Sum()
    - 1; //make zero-index based
```

To revert back, and for the full code and test, see [this](https://gist.github.com/weitzhandler/97089718c5f3bac56bc5521c5317b742) gist.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified *GetColumnIndex* function in the @petelids answer. Result will be zero-based index. If need add 1 for a one-based Index.

```
private static int CellReferenceToIndex(string reference)
{
    foreach (char ch in reference)
    {
        if (Char.IsLetter(ch))
        {
            int value = (int)ch - (int)'A';
            index = (index == 0) ? value : ((index + 1) * 26) + value;
        }
        else
            return index;
    }
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private double CellReferenceToIndex(Cell cell)
    {
        // if Cell is ABC4 => position is
        // = [Aindx * (26^2)] + [BIndx * (27^1)] + [CIndx * (27^0)]
        // = [1     * (26^2)] + [2     * (27^1)] + [3     * (27^0)]

        double index = 0;
        char [] reference = cell.CellReference.ToString().ToUpper().Reverse().ToArray();
        int letterPosition = 0;
       
        foreach (char ch in reference)
        {
            if (char.IsLetter(ch))
            {
                int value = (ch - 'A') + 1; // so A is 1 not 0 
                index += value * Math.Pow(26, letterPosition++);
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
```

Comment: A modification to @Subodh Wasankar
this will get the index correctly for Cols with index > 26

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a new approach to this old question, I use this as a quick method to get the column index for a cell in a row (assuming you're looping through the Cells in a Row in SheetData, as the OP indicates they were).

You can use the ElementsBefore enumerable to count the Cells before the one you're currently looping on, and since that Count is one-based and Element IEnumerables are zero-based, using the Count will give you the column index of the Cell you're currently on (essentially, ElementsBefore + 1 = the current cell's column index).

So, something like this...

```
            For Each r In sht.Elements(Of Row)
                For Each c In sht.Elements(Of Row).ElementAt(r.RowIndex).Elements(Of Cell)
                    Dim iColumnIndex = c.ElementsBefore.Count
                Next
            Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the examples on this thread didn't work beyond Z.

When validating, it's better to perform some Unit tests to confirm the column index is calculated correctly.

Assuming the index count begins from 1, the following can be a useful reference...

[image: Excel letter index calculation]