# Convert a xml to xlsx in C#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have a large grid and i need those data exported to excel.i implemented my solution using openxml, however having nested loops fill each row's columns to set cell values is time consuming.

I'm now trying to export it to xml and then export to xlsx to improve performance.i converted the dataset to xml, now i'm stuck with converting to xlsx. is there a way to convert to xlsx without having nested loops to fill each cell value ?

**UPDATE :** I was able to do it using following library -

[Open XML Format SDK 2.0 Sample - Convert XML to Excel File](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Open-XML-Format-SDK-20-05b5e908/view/SourceCode#content)

Comment: Those two are totally different formats for different purposes.

Comment: @marsze what would you suggest i should do in this scenario ?

Comment: Write your data directly to an Excel format using appropriate libraries.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing your original code but it doesn't sound like converting your data to XML only to convert it to XLSX (which is XML) will be any quicker. Have you tried using a SAX approach with OpenXML? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32787219/3791802) for more details.

Comment: @petelids i'll try this as well.. thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct conversion, but your best bet if you have the XML is to deserialise this so you have access to the data via code, then build an Excel document using an Excel Library (e.g.: `http://epplus.codeplex.com`)