# Flushing memory OpenXML OpenXMLWriter Large DataSets

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a large dataset (100,000 rows, 33 columns). I am using OpenXML to take this data and write it to Excel using the method explained here
[Export big amount of data from XLSX - OutOfMemoryException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690851/export-big-amount-of-data-from-xlsx-outofmemoryexception/32787219#32787219)

It appears to store all of the data in memory when creating the Excel file and then write it all at once because of the XMLWriter. Even in the example above without my own data it appears that this using 700MB-1GB before it finally writes the data.

Is there a way to clear the buffer periodically to limit memory usage or does it have to be all in 1 XMLWriter with how OpenXML works

Comment: I hope you aren't working on the UK NHS track and trace app :-) https://www.itpro.co.uk/business-strategy/public-sector/357325/nhs-test-and-trace-technical-issue-excel-glitch

Comment: Are you using .NET Core? If so, you could be running into [this issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/807) which in turn is caused by [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1544). Unfortunately I don't think there's a fix (other than reverting to the .NET Framework which uses a different System.IO.Packaging).

Comment: @Petelids, you are correct, I just tested this in .Net 4.5 vs .NetCore and its a huge difference in the hundreds of MBs

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similarily sized dataset to yours. And was baffled to see OpenXML use 4.6+GB of memory to write the dataset to xlsx. Also the entire process was slower than Excel Interop (the whole point of using OpenXML was to get rid of needing Excel and beat it in performance).

I too came across similar articles that you linked, that proposed using OpenXmlWriter to solve the memory consumption, but my first crack at it yielded negligible results. I think the memory consumption was still north of 3+ GB, which seemed odd considering writing directly to stream and thus should have less objects in memory etc.

Running some more profiling tests, I found out what was eating the memory. It is the `Cell` object in OpenXML. Even in the code example provided in your link, they are generating `new Cell()` objects inside a for loop, thus ending up with millions of the damn buggers in memory.

I'm not exactly sure why the `Cell` object is as bad as it is. I mean sure in the DOM model, when you append `Cells` inside `Rows`, they are all linked and have references to each other, thus can't be collected from memory until the entire DOM goes out of reference. But in the OpenXmlWriter example provided, the are just new'd, used and thrown away immediately, not linked to any other objects... Guess the `Cell` is just a fat object or perhaps OpenXML links them to some static DOM object behind the scenes.

Anyways, the solution is to just generate **ONE** `Cell` object and reuse it inside the for loop.

Something along the lines of:

```
using (var writer = OpenXmlWriter.Create(workSheetPart))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());
    writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());

    var cell = new Cell(); // only one of these ever exists in memory
    var cv = new CellValue(); // just in case, this too

    foreach (var item in something.Rows)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(item.Row);

        foreach (var cellProxy in item.Cells)
        {
            // reset cell values inorder to reuse again
            cell.CellValue = null;
            cell.InlineString = null;
            cell.CellFormula = null;

            // set cell values to whatever needs to be written
            cell.DataType = cellProxy.DataType;
            if (cellProxy.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
            {
                cv.Text = cellProxy.Text;
                cell.CellValue = cv;
            }
            else if (cellProxy.DataType == CellValues.String)
            {
                cell.CellFormula = cellProxy.Fomula;
            }
            ...
            writer.WriteElement(cell);
        }

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    ...
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

In my code example above, `cellProxy` refers to a custom class I made. It is very similar to the `Cell` class, just without the fatness, storing only the values I need to write to xlsx.

```
internal sealed class CellProxy
{
    internal short ColumnNumber { get; init; }
    internal string Text { get; init; } = String.Empty;
    internal CellValues DataType { get; init; } = CellValues.String;
    internal uint? StyleIndex { get; init; }
    internal CellFormula? Formula { get; init; }
}
```

And the `something` refers to another class of mine, that I use to collect all the data required to pass into OpenXmlWriter, to get the final xlsx file.

```
internal sealed class Something
{
    internal List<Column> Columns { get; } = new List<Column>();
    internal List<(Row Row, List<CellProxy> Cells)> Rows { get; set; } // Row is the OpenXML Row class
    ... etc ...
}
```

So I first query the data from the database, iterate over the result, generate `Row` and `CellProxy` objects that are stored in my `something` class. Then I pass that `something` over to the OpenXmlWriter method, which iterates over my custom classes and writes them to xlsx.

With this approach I ended up using ~700MB to write the xlsx, which is roughly on par with Excel Interop, but a lot faster. Maybe it is possible to save more memory by creating a `RowProxy` class, but I was already happy with the results.

Another neat trick I found, is if you happen to have multiple sheets in your resulting xlsx file. You can multi-thread the generation of those sheets and shave even more seconds off. Somehow the `OpenXmlWriter.Create()` method creates seperate streams, that automagically don't interfere with eachother and the existing OpenXML DOM model in memory, no need to synchronize or lock or anything.

So you start off from your single thread, create all required `WorkSheetPart` objects. Then you can spin of seperate Tasks/threads for each sheet -> to query data from database, iterate over the result, generate `Row`/`CellProxy` objects to represent the data, pass them to seperate `OpenXmlWriter` instances that create the underlying xml. Finally you end up back on your starting single thread, were you call `WorkbookPart.Save();`.