# Performance issue while writing a large Excel File with OfficeOpenXml C#

Tags: c#, excel, performance, openxml

I try to write a large data about 400,000 rows per sheet
and the performance is down about 10 minutes for it:
My snippet Code is:

```
var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Name.Equals("name"))
foreach(IEnumerable<string> row in Data)
{
   foreach(string col in row)
   {
      dynamic data;
      //for date column
      data = DateTime.Parse(col);
      worksheet.Cells[lastRow, LastCell].Style.NumberFormat.Format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
      //for text
      data = col;      

      worksheet.Cells[lastRow, LastCell].Value = data;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, Excel seems like a poor choice for that. What's your question?

Comment: Writing to excel is the requirment from me, so I asked if there is any way to improve performance when I am writing large data, maybe by using another method or class

Comment: And that code doesn't make sense, too. Where do `lastRow` and `LastCell` come from? Why aren't they incremented? The `data = DateTime.Parse(col);` is completely unneccessary ...

Comment: Where does the data come from? A Database? If so, would it make more sense to have the DB export directly to excel and then only maybe do a little "spice-up" afterwards?

Comment: Maybe you could try creating the raw data and then convert / import / zip into your final excel file. Other than that I'm with @Fildor that your current code is unclear on what exactly is going on here.

Comment: writing one row at a time is horribly inefficient.  Much better to build up a array of data in memory and pass it all in one go.  Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536636/write-array-to-excel-range

Comment: I didnt copy all the code but ```lastRow``` and ```lastCell` equals to 1 and they onward by 1

Comment: _"and they onward by 1"_ - not in the code snippet given in the question. Here, it looks like you are writing to the very same cell over and over. So, I am assuming there is some code missing?

Comment: This could potentially be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32787219/3791802